# Twilio API Exporting Sub Accounts

Tags: twilio, twilio-api

Is there an api endpoint to GET all sub accounts of an account? I'm trying to export the list at this location in the twilio browser console:

https://www.twilio.com/console/project/subaccounts.

Since I couldn't find a way to export it, I assumed there might be an endpoint for this data in their api, but I can't seem to find any api docs that reference sub accounts.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the resource.

[List All Accounts](https://www.twilio.com/docs/iam/api/account)

> Read the set of Accounts belonging to the Account used to make the API
> request. This list includes that account, along with any subaccounts
> belonging to it.